# Android 5 - sound loop stutter

Tags: android

I have a ticking sound in my app that works fine on most devices I've tested it on (Nexus 7, SGS4, SGS6) but on Nexus 5 and Nexus 4 there is random stuttering as if the loop is delayed for a fraction of a second.

Some users reported it on Moto X too.

The stuttering is irregular, sometimes it's every loop, sometimes it goes through 5-6 loops before it stutters.

The stuttering is present even when the app is doing nothing, but it is causing a delay in the UI of the app. The seconds on the timer are irregular (in time with the stutters) when ticking is on, but the timer is fine when ticking is off.

I've tried using both mp3 and ogg sound files, same problem.

This problem didn't happen with KitKat.

Logcat reports nothing concurrent with the stutter but sometimes reports:

```
I/AudioFlinger(188): BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4096) from active list on thread 0xb5a9c008
```

and

```
W/AudioTrack(188): releaseBuffer() track 0xb7130628 disabled
due to previous underrun, restarting
```

But this doesn't happen every time there is a stutter, maybe one in ten times.

How I play the sound:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ticking_sound_mp3);
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.start();
```

Comment: have you resolved this problem. I am also having the same issue. If you resolved kindly help.

Comment: Yes, I resolved it by using SoundPool for this particular sound instead of MediaPlayer. My implementation is showing as deprecated and I don't have time to investigate/change that now, so I can't answer my own question until I fix it.